# Exposing wcf service in BizTalk 2010

Tags: wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have ran into this issue the past few weeks ago and I still can not figure out why.

I have a BizTalk orchestration that receives a BizTalk message, processes it and eventually writes it to a file. For simplicity sake, let say, our goal is to take the message (which is actually a survey) and save it to a folder as is. I have created a public receive port to catch the msg and a send port to write the result out to disk.

I have successfully deployed the project and have successfully published it to IIS. I was able to see the WCF service in IIS and have set it to use Framework 4.0. I have set up all the relevant receive and send ports and have started the application successfully from BizTalk management console.  (The receive location was automatically created when I published the wcf service, the send location is a type FILE located in a folder in the computer)

From DefaultSite in IIS, I could see my WCF. However, when I tried `http://localhost/TestSurvey/TestSurvey_Orchestration_1_getSurveyPort.svc,` 
I got the following error:

```
Server Error in '/TestSurvey' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Login failed for user 'Domain\ComputerName$'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'ACAD1\DENBIZDEV$'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'Domain\ComputeName$'.]

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   Microsoft.BizTalk.TransportProxy.Interop.IBTTransportProxy.RegisterIsolatedReceiver(String url, IBTTransportConfig callback) +0
   Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfIsolatedReceiver`2.RegisterIsolatedReceiver(Uri uri) +1028
   Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WebServiceHostFactory`3.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +363
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +1413
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +50
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath) +1172

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/TestSurvey/TestSurvey_Orchestration_1_getSurveyPort.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +901424
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +178638
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +107

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

My question is: what is it that BizTalk was trying to login? Domain\ComputerName$ is definitely not a user. I have not tried to access any database from the orchestration. I believe my IIS was set up correctly as I have created a quick and dirty wcf service test from VS2010 and published it to my IIS, then have successfully created a simple client to consume the wcf service test. I did not encounter the same issue when I created the wcf service test directly.

Any help or hint is highly appreciated!

**EDIT**

I managed to fix this: it was not the web config as it was created by BizTalk. I had to create a special app pool and tied my application to using it. In the app pool I have to use the custom credential that BizTalk is using. Using the built in credentials caused the issue I experienced. My rookie error! Once BizTalk login credential was used, everything went smoothly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The database which is throwing the SQL exception is one of the BizTalk databases, probably the management or SSO DB.

The error is almost certainly being caused by the setup of IIS, whether the app pool identity or the web site security settings.

What is hapenning is that when you call the service for the first time IIS is compiling your service, and to do this it obviously needs access to one of the BizTalk databases, but this call is not authenticated for some reason.

This could be because the app pool user must be a member of the *BizTalk Isolated Host Users* group (which may be called something different depending on how BizTalk was set up.

Comment: Thanks, Hugh. How do I correct the situation? I went into IIS in the application site->Authentication->Advanced Settings->Physical Path Credentials and entered the correct user name and password. I have even created a dedicated app pool and tied the application to use the pool. But BizTalk seems to use [domain\ComputerName$] to access the database which is not correct. I am pretty sure the BizTalk was set up correctly as it has been in the production and other applications have been running on it flawlessly. Maybe I have overlooked some IIS setting as I am new to the whole IIS saga...

Comment: Below is the webconfig.cfg I found in the application folder inside IIS. One thing I do not quite understand is I did tell IIS that my application is using framework 4.0 but the web config appears to be set for framework 2.0. So is the web config in the folder inside IIS used at all? I do not see it accessing or trying to log in any database... Please see my web config in the next comment due to space limitation

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <configSections>
    <section name="bizTalkSettings" type="Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.BizTalkConfigurationSection, Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXX" />
  </configSections>

Comment: <bizTalkSettings>
    <mexServiceHostFactory debug="false">
      <receiveLocationMappings>
    </mexServiceHostFactory>
    <webServiceHostFactory debug="false" />
    <isolatedReceiver disable="false" />
    <btsWsdlExporter disable="false" />
  </bizTalkSettings>

Comment: <appSettings />
  <connectionStrings />
  <system.web>
    <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="mscorlib, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=XXXXXXXXXXXX" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Common, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXX" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXX" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
  </system.web>

Comment: <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviorConfiguration">
          <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" httpsHelpPageEnabled="false" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

Comment: <services>
      <service name="Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.BizTalkServiceInstance" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviorConfiguration">
        <endpoint name="HttpMexEndpoint" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>

Comment: The above is my webconfig in its entirety. Sorry for the multiple parts due to space limitation.

Comment: Thanks but please edit your original post and put the config in there.  It's kind of unreadable in present form.

Comment: Thank you, Hugh for your patience. Very much appreciated. I eventually figured that out based on your hint. It was not the web config as it was created by BizTalk. I had to create a special app pool and tied my application to using it. In the app pool I have to use the custom credential that BizTalk is using. Using the built in credentials caused the issue I experienced. My rookie error! Once BizTalk login credential was used, everything went smoothly. Thanks again for your advice!!!

Comment: No worries - I have edited your OP to include this answer, if you don't mind.

Comment: No problem, Hugh. That's better doing so as I think others may tumble across the same issue as mine a some point in the future.